# Extend Rapidminer

Tags: extend, rapidminer

I'm using Rapidminer 6.4 for connect to my Rapidminer Server.
I download the project from the repository: https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-tutorial
and implement my new operator.
When i execute the installExtension Gradle task, i cant see my new operator in rapidminer 6.4, but if i update to 6.5 i can use my operator.

I cant use RM 6.5 because i cannot connect to my server.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What is your Server version? RM 6.5 can only connect with a 2.5 server.
For more information better ask in the community forum (http://forum.rapid-i.com/) or contact the support if you have a commercial version.

Best,
David

Comment: I'm trying use my operator in RM Studio 6.4. I have RapidMiner Server 2.4.001. I tryed the new operator in RM Studio 6.5 and it run but not appear in RM 6.4.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the important part of your question about the extension.    Unfortunately you can't    build an extension for 6.4 because it is closed source. Only with 6.5 the core of RapidMiner is open source again and allows writing your own extensions.

Comment: Oki!! thanks for your answer, For create my own algorithm i'm using the operator "Execute Script". Regards.